# 四面体(三角錐)の内接球のsympyを探しています。 vbaソルバーでやってみました。

Tags: vba, sympy

①四面体(三角錐)の内接球のsympyを探しています。他言語でも。
②vbaソルバーで実行してみました。vbaコードを短くする方法を教えて下さい。一例しか実行していません。
➂以下のコードの、「Range("A7").Formula」複数行で書けませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

オリジナルポスト
(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,2)
「2021年度 九州大・理系数学問題1(1)」
https://www.densu.jp/kyusyu/21kyusyuspass.pdf

参考
「CASIO＞３点を含む平面の式,４点で形成される四面体の体積」
https://keisan.casio.jp/exec/system/1202458197
https://keisan.casio.jp/exec/system/1202458218
「Wolfram|Alpha」
https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280%2C0%2C0%29%2C%281%2C0%2C0%29%2C%280%2C1%2C0%29%2C%280%2C0%2C2%29
https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E4%B8%89%E8%A7%92%E9%8C%90%EF%BC%880%2C0%2C0%29%2C%281%2C0%2C0%29%2C%280%2C1%2C0%29%2C%280%2C0%2C2%29

```
Const Ax = 0
Const Ay = 0
Const Az = 0
Const Bx = 1
Const By = 0
Const Bz = 0
Const Cx = 0
Const Cy = 1
Const Cz = 0
Const Dx = 0
Const Dy = 0
Const Dz = 2
Function myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
   a = (By - Ay) * (Cz - Az) - (Cy - Ay) * (Bz - Az)
   b = (Bz - Az) * (Cx - Ax) - (Cz - Az) * (Bx - Ax)
   c = (Bx - Ax) * (Cy - Ay) - (Cx - Ax) * (By - Ay)
   d = -(a * Ax + b * Ay + c * Az)
   myHeimen = Array(a, b, c, d)
End Function
Function mySimentaiTaiseki(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
   mySimentaiTaiseki = _
                     ((x4 - x1) * Abs(y2 - y1) * (z3 - z1) - (z3 - z1) * (y3 - y1) _
                    + (y4 - y1) * Abs(z2 - z1) * (x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1) * (z3 - z1) _
                    + (z4 - z1) * Abs(x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)) / 6#
End Function
Function myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
    myDis = Sqr((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2 + (z1 - z2) ^ 2)
End Function
Function myHeron(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)
    s = (myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) + myDis(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3) + myDis(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)) / 2#
    myHeron = Sqr(s * (s - myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)) * (s - myDis(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)) * (s - myDis(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)))
End Function
Function mySimentaiMenseki(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
    mySimentaiMenseki = _
        myHeron(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3) _
      + myHeron(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4) _
      + myHeron(x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x1, y1, z1) _
      + myHeron(x4, y4, z4, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
End Function
Sub aaa_Sankakusui()
    Dim vD As Variant
    Dim vA As Variant
    Dim vB As Variant
    Dim vC As Variant
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
'
MsgBox "四面体(三角錐)の内接球をソルバーで計算します。"
'
    Range("A1") = Ax
    Range("B1") = Ay
    Range("C1") = Az
    Range("A2") = Bx
    Range("B2") = By
    Range("C2") = Bz
    Range("A3") = Cx
    Range("B3") = Cy
    Range("C3") = Cz
    Range("A4") = Dx
    Range("B4") = Dy
    Range("C4") = Dz
    Range("A5") = mySimentaiTaiseki(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    Range("B5") = mySimentaiMenseki(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    Range("C5").Formula = "= A5*3.0/B5"
'
    vD = myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
    vA = myHeimen(Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    vB = myHeimen(Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz, Ax, Ay, Az)
    vC = myHeimen(Dx, Dy, Dz, Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz)
'       "
    Range("E1") = vD(0)
    Range("F1") = vD(1)
    Range("G1") = vD(2)
    Range("H1") = vD(3)
    Range("E2") = vA(0)
    Range("F2") = vA(1)
    Range("G2") = vA(2)
    Range("H2") = vA(3)
    Range("E3") = vB(0)
    Range("F3") = vB(1)
    Range("G3") = vB(2)
    Range("H3") = vB(3)
    Range("E4") = vC(0)
    Range("F4") = vC(1)
    Range("G4") = vC(2)
    Range("H4") = vC(3)
    Range("A7").Formula = "= (Abs(E1 * A6 + F1 * B6 + G1 * C6 + H1) / Sqrt(E1 ^ 2 + F1 ^ 2 + G1 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2   + (Abs(E2 * A6 + F2 * B6 + G2 * C6 + H2) / Sqrt(E2 ^ 2 + F2 ^ 2 + G2 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2 + (Abs(E3 * A6 + F3 * B6 + G3 * C6 + H3) / Sqrt(E3 ^ 2 + F3 ^ 2 + G3 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2  + (Abs(E4 * A6 + F4 * B6 + G4 * C6 + H4) / Sqrt(E4 ^ 2 + F4 ^ 2 + G4 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    SolverReset
    SolverOk setCell:=ws.Range("A7"), _
                   MaxMinVal:=3, _
                   ByChange:=ws.Range("A6:C6"), _
                   EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
     SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
End Sub
'結果
'半径　0.249999801614916
'四面体に内接する球の中心座標　0.249999705 0.249999822 0.249999802
```

Answer (score 0):

vbaソルバー（その2)
変化させるセル(変数セル) に球の半径も追加しました。その結果、表面積と体積の計算が不要になりました。

```
Const Ax = 0
Const Ay = 0
Const Az = 0
Const Bx = 1
Const By = 0
Const Bz = 0
Const Cx = 0
Const Cy = 1
Const Cz = 0
Const Dx = 0
Const Dy = 0
Const Dz = 2
Function myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
   a = (By - Ay) * (Cz - Az) - (Cy - Ay) * (Bz - Az)
   b = (Bz - Az) * (Cx - Ax) - (Cz - Az) * (Bx - Ax)
   c = (Bx - Ax) * (Cy - Ay) - (Cx - Ax) * (By - Ay)
   d = -(a * Ax + b * Ay + c * Az)
   myHeimen = Array(a, b, c, d)
End Function
Sub aaa_Sankakusui()
    Dim vD As Variant
    Dim vA As Variant
    Dim vB As Variant
    Dim vC As Variant
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
'
MsgBox "'四面体(三角錐)の内接球をソルバーで計算します。"
'
    Range("A1") = Ax
    Range("B1") = Ay
    Range("C1") = Az
    Range("A2") = Bx
    Range("B2") = By
    Range("C2") = Bz
    Range("A3") = Cx
    Range("B3") = Cy
    Range("C3") = Cz
    Range("A4") = Dx
    Range("B4") = Dy
    Range("C4") = Dz
'
    vD = myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
    vA = myHeimen(Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    vB = myHeimen(Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz, Ax, Ay, Az)
    vC = myHeimen(Dx, Dy, Dz, Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz)
'       "
    Range("E1") = vD(0)
    Range("F1") = vD(1)
    Range("G1") = vD(2)
    Range("H1") = vD(3)
    Range("E2") = vA(0)
    Range("F2") = vA(1)
    Range("G2") = vA(2)
    Range("H2") = vA(3)
    Range("E3") = vB(0)
    Range("F3") = vB(1)
    Range("G3") = vB(2)
    Range("H3") = vB(3)
    Range("E4") = vC(0)
    Range("F4") = vC(1)
    Range("G4") = vC(2)
    Range("H4") = vC(3)
    Range("A7").Formula = "= (Abs(E1 * A6 + F1 * B6 + G1 * C6 + H1) / Sqrt(E1 ^ 2 + F1 ^ 2 + G1 ^ 2) - D6) ^ 2   + (Abs(E2 * A6 + F2 * B6 + G2 * C6 + H2) / Sqrt(E2 ^ 2 + F2 ^ 2 + G2 ^ 2) - D6) ^ 2 + (Abs(E3 * A6 + F3 * B6 + G3 * C6 + H3) / Sqrt(E3 ^ 2 + F3 ^ 2 + G3 ^ 2) - D6) ^ 2  + (Abs(E4 * A6 + F4 * B6 + G4 * C6 + H4) / Sqrt(E4 ^ 2 + F4 ^ 2 + G4 ^ 2) - D6) ^ 2"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    SolverReset
    SolverOk setCell:=ws.Range("A7"), _
                   MaxMinVal:=3, _
                   ByChange:=ws.Range("A6:D6"), _
                   EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
     SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
End Sub
'結果
'半径 0.249999512642834
'四面体に内接する球の中心座標 0.250000201 0.249999942 0.249998773
```

Answer (score 0):

vbaソルバー（その3)
(その1) について、球の半径を計算しているので、4番目の垂線計算が不要でした。

```
   Const Ax = 0
   Const Ay = 0
   Const Az = 0
   Const Bx = 1
   Const By = 0
   Const Bz = 0
   Const Cx = 0
   Const Cy = 1
   Const Cz = 0
   Const Dx = 0
   Const Dy = 0
   Const Dz = 2
   Function myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
      a = (By - Ay) * (Cz - Az) - (Cy - Ay) * (Bz - Az)
      b = (Bz - Az) * (Cx - Ax) - (Cz - Az) * (Bx - Ax)
      c = (Bx - Ax) * (Cy - Ay) - (Cx - Ax) * (By - Ay)
      d = -(a * Ax + b * Ay + c * Az)
      myHeimen = Array(a, b, c, d)
   End Function
   Function mySimentaiTaiseki(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
      mySimentaiTaiseki = _
                        ((x4 - x1) * Abs(y2 - y1) * (z3 - z1) - (z3 - z1) * (y3 - y1) _
                       + (y4 - y1) * Abs(z2 - z1) * (x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1) * (z3 - z1) _
                       + (z4 - z1) * Abs(x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)) / 6#
   End Function
   Function myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
       myDis = Sqr((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2 + (z1 - z2) ^ 2)
   End Function
   Function myHeron(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)
       s = (myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) + myDis(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3) + myDis(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)) / 2#
       myHeron = Sqr(s * (s - myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)) * (s - myDis(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)) * (s - myDis(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)))
   End Function
   Function mySimentaiMenseki(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
       mySimentaiMenseki = _
           myHeron(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3) _
         + myHeron(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4) _
         + myHeron(x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x1, y1, z1) _
         + myHeron(x4, y4, z4, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
   End Function
   Sub aaa_Sankakusui()
       Dim vD As Variant
       Dim vA As Variant
       Dim vB As Variant
       Dim vC As Variant
       ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
   '
   MsgBox "四面体(三角錐)の内接球をソルバーで計算します。"
   '
       Range("A1") = Ax
       Range("B1") = Ay
       Range("C1") = Az
       Range("A2") = Bx
       Range("B2") = By
       Range("C2") = Bz
       Range("A3") = Cx
       Range("B3") = Cy
       Range("C3") = Cz
       Range("A4") = Dx
       Range("B4") = Dy
       Range("C4") = Dz
       Range("A5") = mySimentaiTaiseki(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
       Range("B5") = mySimentaiMenseki(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
       Range("C5").Formula = "= A5*3.0/B5"
   '
       vD = myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
       vA = myHeimen(Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
       vB = myHeimen(Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz, Ax, Ay, Az)
   '       "
       Range("E1") = vD(0)
       Range("F1") = vD(1)
       Range("G1") = vD(2)
       Range("H1") = vD(3)
       Range("E2") = vA(0)
       Range("F2") = vA(1)
       Range("G2") = vA(2)
       Range("H2") = vA(3)
       Range("E3") = vB(0)
       Range("F3") = vB(1)
       Range("G3") = vB(2)
       Range("H3") = vB(3)
       Range("A7").Formula = "= (Abs(E1 * A6 + F1 * B6 + G1 * C6 + H1) / Sqrt(E1 ^ 2 + F1 ^ 2 + G1 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2   + (Abs(E2 * A6 + F2 * B6 + G2 * C6 + H2) / Sqrt(E2 ^ 2 + F2 ^ 2 + G2 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2 + (Abs(E3 * A6 + F3 * B6 + G3 * C6 + H3) / Sqrt(E3 ^ 2 + F3 ^ 2 + G3 ^ 2) - C5) ^ 2"
       Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
       SolverReset
       SolverOk setCell:=ws.Range("A7"), _
                      MaxMinVal:=3, _
                      ByChange:=ws.Range("A6:C6"), _
                      EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
   End Sub
   '結果
   '半径 0.25
   '四面体に内接する球の中心座標 0.249999819 0.249999981 0.25000015
```

Answer (score 0):

vbaソルバー（その4)
関数にしました。【A1形式】を【R1C1形式】にしました。

```
Const Ax = 0
Const Ay = 0
Const Az = 0
Const Bx = 1
Const By = 0
Const Bz = 0
Const Cx = 0
Const Cy = 1
Const Cz = 0
Const Dx = 0
Const Dy = 0
Const Dz = 2
Function myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
   a = (By - Ay) * (Cz - Az) - (Cy - Ay) * (Bz - Az)
   b = (Bz - Az) * (Cx - Ax) - (Cz - Az) * (Bx - Ax)
   c = (Bx - Ax) * (Cy - Ay) - (Cx - Ax) * (By - Ay)
   d = -(a * Ax + b * Ay + c * Az)
   myHeimen = Array(a, b, c, d)
End Function
Function mySimentaiTaiseki(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
   mySimentaiTaiseki = _
                     ((x4 - x1) * Abs(y2 - y1) * (z3 - z1) - (z3 - z1) * (y3 - y1) _
                    + (y4 - y1) * Abs(z2 - z1) * (x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1) * (z3 - z1) _
                    + (z4 - z1) * Abs(x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)) / 6#
End Function
Function myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
    myDis = Sqr((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2 + (z1 - z2) ^ 2)
End Function
Function myHeron(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)
    s = (myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) + myDis(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3) + myDis(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)) / 2#
    myHeron = Sqr(s * (s - myDis(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)) * (s - myDis(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)) * (s - myDis(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)))
End Function
Function mySimentaiMenseki(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
    mySimentaiMenseki = _
        myHeron(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3) _
      + myHeron(x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4) _
      + myHeron(x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x1, y1, z1) _
      + myHeron(x4, y4, z4, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
End Function
Function myR1C1toA1(i, j)
    myR1C1toA1 = Application.ConvertFormula("R" & i & "C" & j, xlR1C1, xlA1)
End Function
Function myNainaisetukyu(igyo, iretu, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
    Dim vD As Variant
    Dim vA As Variant
    Dim vB As Variant
    Dim vC As Variant
'
    myTaiseki = mySimentaiTaiseki(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    myMenseki = mySimentaiMenseki(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    myR = myTaiseki * 3# / myMenseki
    vD = myHeimen(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
    vA = myHeimen(Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz)
    vB = myHeimen(Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz, Ax, Ay, Az)
'
    myD = "(Abs(" & vD(0) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu) & "+ " & vD(1) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 1) & "+ " & vD(2) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 2) & "+ " & vD(3) & ") / Sqrt(" & vD(0) & " ^ 2 + " & vD(1) & " ^ 2 +" & vD(2) & " ^ 2) - " & myR & ")"
    myA = "(Abs(" & vA(0) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu) & "+ " & vA(1) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 1) & "+ " & vA(2) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 2) & "+ " & vA(3) & ") / Sqrt(" & vA(0) & " ^ 2 + " & vA(1) & " ^ 2 +" & vA(2) & " ^ 2) - " & myR & ")"
    myB = "(Abs(" & vB(0) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu) & "+ " & vB(1) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 1) & "+ " & vB(2) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 2) & "+ " & vB(3) & ") / Sqrt(" & vB(0) & " ^ 2 + " & vB(1) & " ^ 2 +" & vB(2) & " ^ 2) - " & myR & ")"
    Range(myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 4)).Formula = "=" & myD & "^ 2 +" & myA & "^ 2 +" & myB & "^ 2"
'
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    SolverReset
    SolverOk setCell:=ws.Range(myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 4)), _
                   MaxMinVal:=3, _
                   ByChange:=ws.Range(myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu) & ":" & myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 2)), _
                   EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
     SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

     myNainaisetukyu = Array(Range(myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu)).Value, Range(myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu + 1)).Value, Range(myR1C1toA1(igyo, iretu)).Value, myR)
End Function
Sub aaa_Sankakusui()
    Dim myXYZR As Variant
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
    igyo = 1
    iretu = 4
    myXYZR = myNainaisetukyu(igyo, iretu, Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
    Cells(1, 1) = Ax
    Cells(1, 2) = Ay
    Cells(1, 3) = Az
    Cells(2, 1) = Bx
    Cells(2, 2) = By
    Cells(2, 3) = Bz
    Cells(3, 1) = Cx
    Cells(3, 2) = Cy
    Cells(3, 3) = Cz
    Cells(4, 1) = Dx
    Cells(4, 2) = Dy
    Cells(4, 3) = Dz
    Cells(igyo, iretu + 3) = myXYZR(3)
    Cells(igyo, iretu + 4) = ""
End Sub
'結果
'四面体に内接する球の中心座標と半径 0.249999819 0.249999981 0.25000015  0.25
```